# Econometrics : White Test with R

Tags: r

Good morning,

I am trying to realize the white test on my linear model with R. I don't know how to write the R codes to realize the White Test.

Price : house price, in millions dollars

Bdrms : number of bedrooms

Lotsize : size of lot in square feet

Sqrft : size of house in square feet

The linear model is the following :

```
#Linear Model
LinearModel.1 <- lm(PRICE ~ LOTSIZE + LOTSIZE^2 + SQRFT + BDRMS, data=Dataset)
summary(LinearModel.1)


#Breusch-Pagan Test
library(lmtest)
bptest(LinearModel.1, varformula = NULL, studentize = TRUE, data = Dataset)


#White Test
?????????
```

Thanks for your answer
Kind regards,

Answer (score 5):

```
m <- LinearModel.1
data <- Dataset
u2 <- m$residuals^2
y <- fitted(m)
Ru2<- summary(lm(u2 ~ y + I(y^2)))$r.squared
LM <- nrow(data)*Ru2
p.value <- 1-pchisq(LM, 2)
p.value
```

if p.value < 0.05, then Ho (there is no heteroskedasticity) is rejected at 5% significance level and you conclude that there is heteroskedasticity in your model

Answer (score 4):

The White Test has been implemented in the package "bstats". After installing and loading this package, a White Test is performed on a linear model object by simply typing

```
white.test(lm0)
```

See [this](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/bstats/docs/white.test) page for a description and an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.

It's done, it's ok !

On this linear model, I would like to calculate the elasticity of the price compared to lotsize and then the elasticity of the price compared sqrft.

I am trying this way with R : 

print(exp(coef(LinearModel.1)),digits=3) 

(Intercept)     LOTSIZE       SQRFT       BDRMS 
   3.51e-10    1.00e+00    1.13e+00    1.04e+06 

If my R code is correct to calculate the elasticity, that means that the elasticity of lotsize is 1 ? and the elasticity of sqrft is 1.13 ?

Thanks for your answer, Best Regards

Comment: This package is apparently very old, and will not install on my R 3.4.1.

Comment: @steveo'america could you find another package that is still usable?

Answer (score 2):

White's Test is now implemented in the `white_lm` function of `skedastic` package; see
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/skedastic/versions/1.0.0/topics/white_lm

Comment: Is this package still usable? I could not find it. Or does anyone have an alternative for me? Because also whit_lm, whites.htest and white.test are not available any longer (or I just can't find any of them ?)

Comment: Yes, it is still usable. https://cran.r-project.org/package=skedastic

Answer (score 1):

Test can be implemente using the `bptest` function from the `lmtest` package, as follows:

```
reg <- lm(y~x1+x2) # storing regression
bptest(reg, ~ poly(fitted(reg) , 2))
```

Notice the above implements the special form of the test, which uses the fitted value of `y` and its squared value (hence the option `poly(fitted(reg) , 2)` in `bptest`) as regressors in the second stage equation. The normal form uses all regressors, their squared values and interactions as elements in the second stage regression, at the cost of losing degrees of freedom. To implement that form you need to replace `~ poly(fitted(reg) , 2)` with something like `~ x1*x2 + x1*x3 ...`. If you have a lot of regressors, it might be easier to use another package.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a function to reproduce two methods in `R` for White's test in [hendry2007econometric](https://press.princeton.edu/books/paperback/9780691130897/econometric-modeling).

```r
test_white(mod, dat, resi2 ~ x1 + x2 + I(x1^2) + I(x2^2), 3)
```

where the squared residuals are regressed on all regressors and their squares. The degree of freedom is the number of parameters (let's say `k`).

```r
test_white(mod, dat, resi2 ~ x1 + x2 + I(x1^2) + I(x2^2) + I(x1 * x2), 6)
```

where the squared residuals are regressed on all regressors, their squares, and their cross products. The degree of freedom is `k * (k + 1) / 2`.

```r
test_white <- function(mod, dat, f, df1, prob){
  if(missing(prob)){prob = 0.05}

  dat %<>% mutate(resi2 = mod$residuals^2)

  stat <-
    lm(f, data = dat) %>%
    {summary(.)$r.squared} %>%
    {. * nrow(dat)}

  p_value <- 
    stat %>%
    {1 - pchisq(., df1)}

  results <- tibble(
    whi = "White", stat = stat, df1 = df1, df2 = nrow(dat) - df1,  
    p_value = p_value,prob = prob, if_accept = {p_value <= prob}, 
    if_pass = {p_value >= prob}
  )
  return(results)
}
```

I think the [way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28048564/10181743) @Mike K does is alright, which is actually to test if an `lm` model based on the scale-location plot is significant. The scale-location plot refers to when you [plot diagnostics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/65864/231405) for an `lm` object by `plot.lm(model, which = 3)`.